# Help plotting a polynomial in MATLAB.

Tags: matlab

This time I want to plot he interpolation polynomial with the coefficients given by the following code:

```
%Code for the polynimial interpolation.
%We first define the points where we want that our polynimial passes
%through


x0=-pi/2;
y0=-1;
x1=0;
y1=0;
x2=pi/2;
y2=1;
x3=pi;
y3=0;

x=[x0,x1,x2,x3];
y=[y0,y1,y2,y3];
%Now we perform the algorithm.

c=zeros(4,1);
c(1)=y(1);
for k=2:4
    d=x(k)-x(k-1);
    u=c(k-1);
    for i=(k-2):-1:1
        u=u*(x(k)-x(i))+c(i);
        d=d*(x(k)-x(i));
    end
    c(k)=(y(k)-u)/d;


end
disp(c)
```

The thing is that I want to plot the results, so I have tried the following:

```
plot(x,y)
x1=0:4;
for i=-4:4
y1=c(1)+c(2)*(x1-x(1))+c(3)*(x1-x(1))*(x1-x(2))+c(4)*(x1-x(1))*(x1-x(2))*(x1-x(3))*(x1-x(4));
end
```

and

```
y_1 = @(x)-0.6729+4.8266*(x-x(1))-0.4855*(x-x(1))*(x-x(2))+0.0312*(x-x(1))*(x-x(2))*(x-x(3))+3.044*(x-x(1))*(x-x(2))*(x-x(3))*(x-x(4));

x_1 = 0:0.1:33.5;

plot(x_1,y_1(x_1))
```

But the thing is that anyone worked, so Can someone help me to plot this polynomial please?

How Can I do this without using @(x)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, when you multiply two vectors pointwise, you have to use

```
.*
```

instead of

```
*
```

For instance, you should change

```
y_1 = @(x)-0.6729+4.8266*(x-x(1))-0.4855*(x-x(1))*(x-x(2))+0.0312*(x-x(1))*(x-x(2))*(x-x(3))+3.044*(x-x(1))*(x-x(2))*(x-x(3))*(x-x(4));
```

to

```
 y_1 = @(x)-0.6729+4.8266*(x-x(1))-0.4855*(x-x(1)).*(x-x(2))+0.0312*(x-x(1)).*(x-x(2)).*(x-x(3))+3.044*(x-x(1)).*(x-x(2)).*(x-x(3)).*(x-x(4));
```

---

EDIT: to remove the `@x`, you could just have

```
x_1 = 0:0.1:33.5;
y_1 = -0.6729+4.8266*(x_1-x_1(1))-0.4855*(x_1-x_1(1)).*(x_1-x_1(2))+ ...
      0.0312*(x_1-x_1(1)).*(x_1-x_1(2)).*(x_1-x_1(3))+...
      3.044*(x_1-x_1(1)).*(x_1-x_1(2)).*(x_1-x_1(3)).*(x_1-x_1(4));

plot(x_1,y_1)
```

I put in the `...`'s to write a multiline equation, since that's considered better practice.

Comment: Ok, let me try that :), just a second.

Comment: How can I do it with out @(x)?

Comment: The '@(x)' appears since you have defined 'y' as an anonymous function.  If you don't want to have that appear, you could just define 'y_1' to be equal to all of that stuff before calling 'plot'.

Comment: Ok, so how does te code goes ? Thanks

Comment: @user162343, I added a bit to show you an example.

Comment: Right so let me check it, if I have further questions , can I let you know ?

Comment: @user162343 Sure.  It might take me some time to reply, though.

Comment: Ok, hope this will not be the case  just give a little bit of time because here is a little bit late that is the problem jajajaja but I will try to check this the fast I can